# XRDP rejecting login

Tags: remote-desktop, redhat-enterprise-linux

I am on a windows 7 computer trying to access to a RHEL7 system via windows remote desktop.

Until today I (and others in my department) have been able to login to the RHEL machine using xrdp.

**Today suddenly xrdp started rejecting the connections.** I can see the green background login screen but it rejects the credentials (and those are fine).

I can ping to the server, connect via putty and use filezilla, but the remote desktop connection rejects the session login.

I have also tried to connect via remote desktop to another CENTOS machine and it works fine.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

**~/.xsession-errors** :

```
gnome-session-is-accelerated: llvmpipe detected.
```

**/var/log/xrdp.log:**

```
[20171031-13:55:53] [DEBUG] TLSv1.2 enabled
[20171031-13:55:53] [DEBUG] TLSv1.1 enabled
[20171031-13:55:53] [DEBUG] TLSv1 enabled
[20171031-13:55:53] [DEBUG] Security layer: requested 3, selected 1
[20171031-13:55:53] [INFO ] connected client computer name: SPENATE7
[20171031-13:55:53] [INFO ] TLS connection established from 192.168.197.176 port 51321: TLSv1.2 with cipher AES256-GCM-SHA384
[20171031-13:55:53] [DEBUG] xrdp_00007c0e_wm_login_mode_event_00000001
[20171031-13:55:53] [INFO ] Loading keymap file /etc/xrdp/km-0000040a.ini
[20171031-13:55:53] [WARN ] local keymap file for 0x0000040a found and doesn't match built in keymap, using local keymap file
[20171031-13:55:58] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: connecting to sesman ip 127.0.0.1 port 3350
[20171031-13:55:59] [INFO ] xrdp_wm_log_msg: sesman connect ok
[20171031-13:55:59] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: sending login info to session manager, please wait...
[20171031-13:55:59] [DEBUG] return value from xrdp_mm_connect 0
[20171031-13:56:05] [INFO ] xrdp_wm_log_msg: login failed for display 0
[20171031-13:56:05] [DEBUG] xrdp_mm_module_cleanup
[20171031-13:56:05] [DEBUG] Closed socket 18 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:46890)
```

**/var/log/xrdp-sesman.log** :

```
[20171031-12:58:20] [ERROR] X server -- no display in range is available
[20171031-12:58:20] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20171031-13:01:28] [INFO ] shutting down sesman 1
[20171031-13:01:28] [DEBUG] Closed socket 7 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20171031-13:01:29] [CORE ] shutting down log subsystem...
[20171031-13:01:29] [DEBUG] libscp initialized
[20171031-13:01:29] [INFO ] starting xrdp-sesman with pid 14292
[20171031-13:01:29] [INFO ] listening to port 3350 on 127.0.0.1
[20171031-13:01:41] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 35854
[20171031-13:01:41] [INFO ] ++ created session (access granted): username sanpen, ip 192.168.197.176:60904 - socket: 12
[20171031-13:01:41] [INFO ] starting Xvnc session...
[20171031-13:01:41] [DEBUG] Closed socket 9 (AF_INET 0.0.0.0:5910)
[20171031-13:01:41] [DEBUG] Closed socket 9 (AF_INET 0.0.0.0:6010)
[20171031-13:01:42] [DEBUG] Closed socket 9 (AF_INET 0.0.0.0:6210)
[20171031-13:01:42] [DEBUG] Closed socket 9 (AF_INET 0.0.0.0:5911)
[20171031-13:01:42] [DEBUG] Closed socket 9 (AF_INET 0.0.0.0:6011)
[20171031-13:01:42] [DEBUG] Closed socket 9 (AF_INET 0.0.0.0:6211)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did have the same issue, that's how I solved but I don't really feel comfortable with the solution.

You need to change in both **sesmain.in** and **sesman.ini** the field `MaxSessions` to a greater number than you already have. It seems that some sessions are not set freed in a proper way.
Both files are in `/etc/xrdp`. You would need sudo privileges to edit them.

Comment: It seems you have mistakenly asked your a question in your answer to this question.  It is not possible for us to answer that question.  Questions asked in an answer should be removed.  If you have a question, you want an answer to, you should asked it the proper way by submitting a question.

Comment: Worked for me as well (changed from 50 to 100). Do you know how could I delete these sessions?

Answer (score 1):

#### The remote desktop connection rejects the session login.

> `xRDP` writes some log files into your system.  We would recommend you
>   to have a look at these log files. These logs files might provide
>   useful insight about the problem you are encountering.
>
> You should look at the following files:
>
> ```
> ~/.xsession-errors
> /var/log/xrdp.log
> /var/log/xrdp-sesman.log
> ```

Source [Question 20 – I still cannot login to my XRDP session.  Where should I look for troubleshooting my issues?](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=5984)

Comment: Hi, Indeed I have seen such suggestions in other forums. I don't see anything critical. See the edit for the log files.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 noteworthy minor caveats.

1. Ensure the case sensitivity of the username matches what was originally configured.  I just had a ticket come in for this same problem, and the user was attempting to use "Admin" instead of "admin" in this case.
2. Try connecting with 15- or 16-bit color depth instead of 24-bit.

End user reported:

```
    connecting to sesman ip 127.0.0.1 port 3350
    sesman connect ok
    sending login info to session manager, please wait...
    login failed for display 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it with the following:

- Edit `/etc/X11/Xwrapper.config`
- Change `allowed_users=console` to `allowed_users=anybody`
- `sudo service xrdp stop`
- `sudo service xrdp start`

Answer (score 1):

Check /var/log/apt/history.log, this was part of the upgrade from this morning (2019-01-10)

xrdp:amd64 (0.6.1-2, 0.6.1-2ubuntu0.1)

I then downgraded ...

sudo apt-get install xrdp=0.6.1-2

It now works

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same error. And I fixed it by getting my asking server provider to reset my password. It may work for you too!

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this same error as well, from MacOS 10.15.3 to Centos 8.  Reducing the screen resolution in the Microsoft Remote Desktop Version 10.3.4 (1688) client software to 1680x1050 mostly resolved the issue.  When connecting, the RDC will sometimes hang and give you the beach ball, but if you Force Quit RDC and then relaunch/reconnect it connects instantly.

Answer (score 0):

I hope my solution and case will help somebody. Namely, I ran into this issue when I tried to get GUI for Kali on Windows 10 WSL2. Remote Desktop application was not able to connect with WSL2 Kali through RDP. In `/var/log/xrdp.log` I had entries:

```
[20210523-19:03:48] [INFO ] xrdp_wm_log_msg: sesman connect ok
[20210523-19:03:48] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: sending login info to session manager, please wait...
[20210523-19:03:48] [DEBUG] return value from xrdp_mm_connect 0
[20210523-19:03:50] [INFO ] xrdp_wm_log_msg: login failed for display 0
[20210523-19:03:50] [DEBUG] xrdp_mm_module_cleanup
```

Then I checked `/var/log/xrdp-sesman.log` and found that there were almost no entries for any sessions that were attempted!
I figured out that port `3350` was used by Ubuntu WSL2 (not Kali WSL2) that I had. Changing the port from  `ListenPort=3350` to `ListenPort=3349` in `/etc/xrdp/sesman.ini` resolved the issue for me.
Here is the part of `/etc/xrdp/sesman.ini` where I changed `ListenPort`:

```
[Globals]
ListenAddress=127.0.0.1
ListenPort=3349 ; <== THIS is CHANGE! From 3350 to 3349
EnableUserWindowManager=true
; Give in relative path to user's home directory
UserWindowManager=startwm.sh
; Give in full path or relative path to /etc/xrdp
DefaultWindowManager=startwm.sh
; Give in full path or relative path to /etc/xrdp
ReconnectScript=reconnectwm.sh
```

I hope it will help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

Let me chime in here. I just wasted a day and found out that my issue was related to something completely different. One of my co-workers hat die idea to change GDM to auto login a certain user. He did not test his changes and the next employee how needed the session encountered the problem that the session could not be started. In the mean time I created another user and was able to successfully login, so it wasn't the super complex password he also used to make things worse.

So auto login option or some other changes from the default are worth looking for particularly if you are not using the system all alone or you are teh type of person who copies a lot of configuration options with knowing what they will to.